# Keeping object selected in the Outliner after deselecting it in 3D View

Tags: python, maya

[image: graph]

I've created my own Graph Editor and Outliner, my problem is that I want to be able to keep the previously selected object selected in my Outliner so that it continues to display on the Graph Editor, but I'm also still able to select the attributes of that object and have the Graph Editor update.

The effect I'm trying to get is what you get from the `Auto Load Selected Objects` feature in Autodesk Maya's Graph Editor.

I've tried a few things with the `selectionConnections`, but I haven't quite got my head around it. I can keep the Outliner and Graph Editor from changing by using the `lock = 1` code, but the Graph Editor no longer updates with the attributes of the selected object.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.window( w = 500 )
mc.paneLayout( configuration = 'vertical2', swp = 1, ps = [ 2, 70, 0 ] )
mc.frameLayout( w = 150, h = 100, lv = 0 )

mc.outlinerEditor( mainListConnection = 'modelList', 
                   selectionConnection = 'modelList', 
                   showShapes = 1, 
                   showReferenceNodes = 0, 
                   showReferenceMembers = 0, 
                   showAttributes = 1, 
                   showSelected = 0,         
                   highlightActive = 1, 
                   showAnimCurvesOnly = 0, 
                   autoExpand = 1,
                   showConnected = 1, 
                   showDagOnly = 0, 
                   ignoreDagHierarchy = 1, 
                   expandConnections = 0, 
                   showCompounds = 0,     
                   showNumericAttrsOnly = 0,
                   autoSelectNewObjects = 0, 
                   doNotSelectNewObjects = 1, 
                   transmitFilters = 0, 
                   showSetMembers = 1,     
                   setFilter = 'defaultSetFilter',
                   lck = 1 )

mc.setParent( '..' )
mc.frameLayout( w = 1, h = 100, lv = 0 )
mc.animCurveEditor( mlc = 'modelList', dak = 1, di = 0, dat = 'off' )
mc.setParent( '..' )
mc.showWindow()
```

The issue is that when I deselect the object the Outliner highlight turns off the object and the Graph Editor goes blank. I want this to ignore new selections and keep the current object selected, but still able to individually select the attributes.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Update

Ok, I think I've got an answer for this:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

Xsl = (mc.ls (sl=1, sn=1))[0]

def toastFUNC (arg=0):
    mc.animCurveEditor (curveEditor, e=1, lck=1)

mc.window(w=500)
mc.paneLayout( configuration='vertical2', swp=1, ps=[2, 70, 0] )    
mc.frameLayout(w=150, h=100, lv=0)

mc.outlinerEditor(mlc='modelList', slc='modelList', showReferenceNodes=0, showReferenceMembers=0,    showAttributes=1, showSelected=0, highlightActive=1, showAnimCurvesOnly=0, autoExpand=1,
showConnected=1, showDagOnly=0, ignoreDagHierarchy=1, expandConnections=0, showCompounds=0,   showNumericAttrsOnly=0,
autoSelectNewObjects=0, doNotSelectNewObjects=1, transmitFilters=0, showSetMembers=1,    setFilter='defaultSetFilter', lck=1, sec=toastFUNC)

mc.setParent('..')

mc.frameLayout(w=1, h=100, lv=0)
curveEditor = mc.animCurveEditor(mlc='modelList', slc='modelList', dak=1, di=0, dat='off', lck=1)
mc.setParent('..')
mc.showWindow()
```

If anyone has any tips for using the selectionConnection I'd still love to hear some :)

Comment: Please find my completed answer above. Let me know if it was useful.

Comment: Hey Kartikg3, although your solution worked i've found that the above better matches my desired effect. Many thanks for your help though!

Comment: No problem. I was aiming for reducing disruption of user experience from a generic point of view.

Answer (score 1):

@Adam, the technique you have proposed works but interferes with the active selection also, which is not ideal. Ideally, your window and what's selected after your window is open must be decoupled. The way you can do that is by:

1. Making a `selectionConnection`. [See the docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/selectionConnection.html#flaglock).

**EDIT:** This selection connection need not be locked.
To do this:

```
sel_conn_name = "graphSelConn"
if cmds.selectionConnection(sel_conn_name, q=True, exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI(sel_conn_name)

cmds.selectionConnection(sel_conn_name, lock=False)
```

*Note*: `selectionConnections` are physical UI objects, whose names need to be unique to be re-created, just like windows. Hence we do the exists check as seen above.

**EDIT:**
This will be the selection connection that your `outlinerEditor` would be using.

We make another selection connection that the `animCurveEditor` would be using:

```
sel_conn_curves_name = "graphSelConnCurves"
if mc.selectionConnection(sel_conn_curves_name, q=True, exists=True):
    mc.deleteUI(sel_conn_curves_name)

mc.selectionConnection(sel_conn_curves_name)
```

**Why do we use 2 selection connections and what are the `mainListConnection` flags for?**

The `mainListConnection` would be the selectionConnection that will be used as the primary/initial **source** for this editor.
The `selectionConnection` flag will hold the `selectionConnection` object that will receive/hold the objects that are selected on this editor.

So in our case, the `outlinerEditor` will have 'modelList' as its mainListConnection because it needs to start off showing objects that were selected/active. The `animCurveEditor` would need the objects selected on the `outlinerEditor` as its primary source, so we use the `outlinerEditor`'s `selectionConnection` holder.

2. Feeding the `selectionConnection` to your respective `outlinerEditor` and `animCurveEditor`. This can be done by passing our `sel_conn_name` to the `selectionConnection` flags of both the `outlinerEditor` and `animCurveEditor`.
3. **EDIT:** Locking the selection connection *ONLY* for the `outlinerEditor`, so it won't be affected by changes to the active list. You do this by setting `lockMainConnection=True` for it. [Check the docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/animCurveEditor.html#flaglockMainConnection). You then feed the `outlinerEditor's` `selectionConnection`, which is `sel_conn_name` to the `mainListConnection` of `animCurveEditor`. You give the `animCurveEditor` it's own `selectionConnection` to work with, in this case `sel_conn_curves_name`. It is important to unlock main connection of the `animCurveEditor` as we want it to reflect selected attributes. We do this by setting `lockMainConnection=False`.

Here is the modified script for you:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.window(w=500)
mc.paneLayout(configuration='vertical2', swp=1, ps=[2, 70, 0])
mc.frameLayout(w=150, h=100, lv=0)

sel_conn_name = "graphSelConn"
if mc.selectionConnection(sel_conn_name, q=True, exists=True):
    mc.deleteUI(sel_conn_name)

mc.selectionConnection(sel_conn_name)


sel_conn_curves_name = "graphSelConnCurves"
if mc.selectionConnection(sel_conn_curves_name, q=True, exists=True):
    mc.deleteUI(sel_conn_curves_name)

mc.selectionConnection(sel_conn_curves_name)

mc.outlinerEditor(mainListConnection='modelList',
                  selectionConnection=sel_conn_name,
                  lockMainConnection=True,
                  showShapes=1, 
                  showReferenceNodes=0, 
                  showReferenceMembers=0, 
                  showAttributes=1, 
                  showSelected=0, 
                  highlightActive=1, 
                  showAnimCurvesOnly=0, 
                  autoExpand=1,
                  showConnected=1, 
                  showDagOnly=0, 
                  ignoreDagHierarchy=1, 
                  expandConnections=0, 
                  showCompounds=0, 
                  showNumericAttrsOnly=0,
                  autoSelectNewObjects=0,
                  doNotSelectNewObjects=1,
                  transmitFilters=0,
                  showSetMembers=1,
                  setFilter='defaultSetFilter'
                  )
mc.setParent('..')

mc.frameLayout(w=1, h=100, lv=0)

mc.animCurveEditor(mlc=sel_conn_name,
                   slc=sel_conn_curves_name,
                   lockMainConnection=False,
                   dak=0,
                   di=0,
                   dat='off')
mc.setParent('..')
mc.showWindow()
```

Hope that was useful.

Comment: That's great, the only problem with this is that i'm unable to have any of the attributes in the outliner become isolated on the graph. It'll only display the object that it opens on. How would you get around this?