# How can I manually interact with a custom Graph Editor in Maya (Using Python)

Tags: python, graph, editor, maya

I've been practicing my python/mel coding and have been interested in creating a graph editor. I did a lot of research online and found this previous question ([How can I keep an object selected in the outliner after physically deselecting it in the 3d view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107009/how-can-i-keep-an-object-selected-in-the-outliner-after-physically-deselecting-i)) that helped me out a lot. However, I am having an issue were I cannot manually edit the curves that are generated. I'm unsure as to why this is happening and can't seem to find any clear documentation. (I've looked up the command references for mel/python in Maya but it doesn't seem to have detailed explanations).

To be more clear, my goal is to use my mouse to move the curve information based on keyframe data (Exactly like Maya's own graph editor). I am using the code solution from the previous example (edited to include my own selection connections and frame conventions).

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I decided the easiest thing was to use Maya's own graph editor within my interface

```
# GRAPH ROW
# Section for the graph editor to allow the user to change attributes
paneLayout( configuration='single', parent=form, width=620, height=320 )
# queries Maya's graph editor and places it within my frame
graph = cmds.getPanel(scriptType='graphEditor')
cmds.scriptedPanel( graph[0], e=True, unParent=True)
cmds.scriptedPanel( graph[0], e=True, parent=frame1)
```